# objects disappear while sliding over them while they fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein

I have a problem with some jQuery fadeIn effect. This is actually on this website: [website here](http://tucado.com/index.html). The problem appears when you select any option from the main menu and during page load up (menu is fading In) slide over the menu buttons. Then some of them (the one you were fading over) will not appear, or will appear slightly faded.
I have used this code for buttons:

HTML:

```
            <nav>
                <a id="b1" href="index.html"><span>01. <strong>ABOUT US</strong></span><div></div></a>
                <a id="b2" href="webdesign.html"><span>02. <strong>WEBSITE DESIGN</strong></span><div></div></a>
                <a id="b3" href="mobile-websites.html"><span>03. <strong>MOBILE WEBSITES</strong></span><div></div></a>
                <a id="b4" href="captive-portals.html"><span>04. <strong>CAPTIVE PORTALS</strong></span><div></div></a>
                <a id="b5" href="portfolio.html"><span>05. <strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></span><div></div></a>
                <a id="b6" href="contact-us.html"><span>06. <strong>CONTACT US</strong></span><div></div></a>
            </nav>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("nav a").mouseenter(function () {
    $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
        'height': '65px'
    }, 100);
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        'padding-top': '5px'
    }, 300);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
        'height': '0px'
    }, 300);
    
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        'padding-top': '25px'
    }, 500);
});

    
$('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6, #b7').hide();
    
for (var i=1; i<99; i++) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('#b'+i).fadeIn(500);
     }, 300+100*i);
  })(i);
}
 });
```

JS FIDDLE HERE:
http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/9hhZW/

(slide mouse over buttons while fading in and you will know what I mean).
Basically I want buttons to appear normally so the sliding mouse over them won't interrupt them in fading to 100%.

Thank you in advance for any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return from your mouseenter and mouseleave handlers if the element is being animated, you can do that with `.is(':animated')` .

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/9hhZW/1/)

**UPDATE:** My above solution will exit when the element is animating, but that also included the own animations of the mouseenter, mouseleave handlers, we want to only exit if it's the fadein animation, so to distinguish that I set a property called `fading` when starting to fading an element and remove it when it ends the fade effect, so we can check for this property in the mouseenter mouseleave handlers.

See [new working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/9hhZW/4/)

And I paste the code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav a").mouseenter(function () {
        if ($(this).data('fading'))  //EXIT IF WE ARE FADING
            return;
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '65px'
        }, 100);
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '5px'
        }, 300);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        if ($(this).data('fading'))  //EXIT IF WE ARE FADING
            return;
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '0px'
        }, 300);

        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '25px'
        }, 500);
    });


    $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6, #b7').hide();

    for (var i=1; i<99; i++) {
      (function(i){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#b'+i).data('fading', true).fadeIn(500, function() {
               $(this).data('fading', false);
            });
         }, 300+100*i);
      })(i);
    }   
 });
```

Comment: thanks. there problem is sorted, but now when you mouse-out buttons the animation does not come back to the previous state.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer for explanation of that problem and a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you stop the elements animation before they are initialized first (first fadeIn();)

I've created a fiddle for you using the fadeIn() callback to append the hover after showing first time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var appendHover = function () {    
    $("nav a").mouseenter(function () {
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '65px'
        }, 100);
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '5px'
        }, 300);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('div', this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'height': '0px'
        }, 300);

        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'padding-top': '25px'
        }, 500);
    });
}


    $('#b1, #b2, #b3, #b4, #b5, #b6, #b7').hide();

    for (var i=1; i<99; i++) {
      (function(i){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#b'+i).fadeIn(500, function() {appendHover();});
         }, 300+100*i);
      })(i);
    }   
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9hhZW/2/

Comment: unfortunately problem still exists. Slightly more visible buttons but the problem still exist.